# on sroling recyclerview cardview comming in one page

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I m developing android app since 1 year its working fine but now some strange behavior. Recycler view displaying multiple card on screen (6 card in one page)  but when I am scrolling it is displaying only one card on top and blank after showing card .  I didn't torched code I m using wrap content in recycler view.recyclerview is coming correct but after scorning new cardview means 7 number is coming in full page next in full page and same see image...--
   [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jQxS.png-----)

[iamge  whiout scrooling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb1R2.png)

Comment: Try to set `match_parent` for `layout_height` in `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I changed wrap content in cardview now its working fine

Comment: `match_parent ` for RecyclerVIew. you can try it.

Comment: no its taking all page if I m trying match parent

Comment: roan cam you do upvote   beacase I m blocked I cant ask quiestion

Comment: Post your adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

For the custom layout that you are using please set height of parent layout to be WRAP_CONTENT. Hope that helps

Comment: ya its wrap content

Comment: see image may be helpfull

Comment: you can use view holder to manage the same and avoid the scrolling issue

Comment: how to use did you understand my problem

Comment: did you seen image both image

Comment: Yes I have seen.  You need to use    "static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder"  and when ever you access the widgets you have to access them by viewHolder object

Comment: so  explain me how to manage ?? can you tell me detail about holder how to manage

Comment: // code for View Holder class 
public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
        CardView card_view;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        
            card_view=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        }
    }

Comment: // now when ever you set data in any widget use the code below

 @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_add_estimate, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      
            holder.txtView.setText("Hi");
        }